# O que é um "protocolo sem estado", como o HTTP?

Tags: http

Ultimamente eu tenho lido muito material sobre web e sempre vejo alguém mencionando que o HTTP é um **protocolo sem estado** (*stateless protocol*).

Segue um trecho retirado da [RFC 2616](http://g) (*ênfase minha*)

> The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is an application-level
>      protocol for distributed, collaborative, hypermedia information
>      systems. **It is a generic, stateless, protocol** which can be used for
>      many tasks beyond its use for hypertext, such as name servers and
>      distributed object management systems, through extension of its
>      request methods, error codes and headers [47].

O que faz com que o HTTP seja um protocolo sem estado?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/18246)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Em computação, um protocolo sem estado (do inglês stateless) é um protocolo de comunicação que considera cada requisição como uma transação independente que não está relacionada a qualquer requisição anterior, de forma que a comunicação consista de pares de requisição e resposta independentes. Um protocolo sem estado não requer que o servidor retenha informação ou estado de sessão sobre cada parceiro de comunicação para a duração de várias requisições. Em contraste, um protocolo que exija a manutenção do estado interno no servidor é conhecido como um protocolo com estado.

Exemplos de protocolos sem estado incluem o Protocolo de Internet (IP), que é a base para a Internet, e o Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), que é a base da comunicação de dados para a World Wide Web.

[Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_sem_estado)