# Adicionando várias linhas GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou tentando incluir várias linhas em um GridView, porém ele não adiciona as linhas, ele sempre substitui a primeira.

Gostaria de saber como faço para ele adicionar várias linhas, e não substituindo a primeira.

Segue o código de como estou fazendo atualmente:

```
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Nome");
dt.Columns.Add("Quantidade");
dt.Columns.Add("Valor");
dt.Columns.Add("Desconto");
dt.Columns.Add("Valor Final");
dt.Columns.Add("Quitar", typeof(bool));
DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
dataRow[0] = txtidprodutoAdd.Text;
dataRow[1] = cbProdutoAdd.SelectedItem;
dataRow[2] = UpQuantidade.Text;
dataRow[3] = txtValorAdd.Text;
dataRow[4] = txtDescontoAdd.Text;
dataRow[5] = txtValorFinalAdd.Text;
dataRow[6] = true;
dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
GridView5.DataSource = dt;
GridView5.DataBind();
```

Comment: Ok, sobre a dúvida: onde você está tentando inserir uma segunda linha? No código só tem uma linha sendo criada.

Comment: É o mesmo código, tenho um button que abre um modal, através do preenchimento dos dados, é incluído no gridView. E está substituindo a linha, utilizo esse código, ele que está no button.

Comment: Estou escrevendo uma resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, fiz desta forma:

```html
 if (Session["dt1"] != null)
            {
                dt1 = (DataTable)Session["dt1"];
            }
            else
            {
                dt1.Columns.Add("ID");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Nome");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Quantidade");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Valor");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Desconto");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Valor Final");
                dt1.Columns.Add("Quitar", typeof(bool));

            }



            dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
            dr1["ID"] = txtidprodutoAdd.Text;
            dr1["Nome"] = cbProdutoAdd.SelectedItem;
            dr1["Quantidade"] = UpQuantidade.Text;
            dr1["Valor"] = txtValorAdd.Text;
            dr1["Desconto"] = txtDescontoAdd.Text;
            dr1["Valor Final"] = txtValorFinalAdd.Text;
            dr1["Quitar"] = true;
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);
            GridView5.DataSource = dt1;
            GridView5.DataBind();
            Session["dt1"] = dt1;
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está tratando uma aplicação web como se fosse uma aplicação desktop normal. É preciso atentar que uma [aplicação web é sempre *stateless*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119549/18246), ou seja, nenhum tipo de estado é mantido entre uma requisição e outra, elas são independentes.

Então sempre que a requisição é recebida, um novo `DataTable` é criado, independentemente se na requisição anterior ele já tenha sido criado ou não. Existem algumas maneiras de se lidar com isso e, **muito provavelmente** já exista um mecanismo do próprio WebForms, uma vez que os componentes da interface gráfica mantém uma espécie de estado entre uma requisição e outra (i.e.: os `TextBoxes` mantêm os valores digitados).

Como eu não conheço WebForms, não sei se a minha solução é a melhor, mas, pela lógica, ela funciona. O que deve ser feito é capturar o `DataSource` do `DataGridView` e adicionar uma linha neste `DataSource`.

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) GridView5.DataSource;

DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
dataRow[0] = 123;
dataRow[1] = "asd";
dataRow[2] = 123;
dataRow[3] = 50.0;
dataRow[4] = 0;
dataRow[5] = 50;
dataRow[6] = true;
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma e não deu certo, estou tentando adaptar o código, para ver se funciona.

Comment: Infelizmente desta forma também não deu certo. Continuo com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Quando eu tiver um tempo eu tento algo, @marianac_costa

Comment: Consegui resolver @jbueno , obrigado.