# Perdendo elementos do array ao mudar de pagina?

Tags: php

Estou aprendendo PHP e estou tentando inserir valores em um `array` através de um `input`, escrevo um valor no `input` e clico no botão Add Array e vai pro arquivo PHP onde tem a função pra adicionar o valor escrito no array criado, porém ele só insere o ultimo valor, se eu tentar inserir 5 numeros, quando eu pedir pra mostrar só vai ter o ultimo numero inserido, os 4 primeiros terão sido perdidos, porque?

HTML:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Array</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Add</h2>
    <hr>
    <div style="width: 50%; margin-left: 30px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 300px;">
            <form method="POST" action="function/add.php?action=addArray">
                <label for="valor">Valor:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-info">Add Array</button>
            </form>   
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['action']))
{
    switch ($_GET['action']) 
    {
        case 'addArray':
            $cesta = array(); //Cria variavel tipo array.
            $valorInserir = $_POST['valor']; //Atribui valor pra variavel
            array_push($cesta, $valorInserir); //Insere no array CESTA o valor
            header("Location: ../index.php"); //Direciona pra index novamente
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é um “protocolo sem estado”, como o HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119549/5878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É exatamente o que todas as respostas deste post dizem.

No seu caso basta fazer assim:

```
session_start();

if(!empty($_GET['action'])){

    switch ($_GET['action']) 
    {
        case 'addArray':

            $valorInserir = $_POST['valor']; //Atribui valor pra variavel
            //armazenando os valores anteriores concatenados com o novo valor usando separador virgula
            $_SESSION['cesta'] = $_SESSION['cesta'].",".$valorInserir;

            //header("Location: ../index.php"); //Direciona pra index novamente

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    $meuArray = explode(',', $_SESSION['cesta']);
    print_r($meuArray);
}
```

> Sessions são arquivos temporários que guardam informações no servidor. Para que servem? Tem a mesma funcionalidade do famoso COOKIE, mas a vantagem é que o computador do cliente não precisa estar habilitado para usá-la
>
> Para iniciarmos uma session, usamos a função [session_start](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que você submete o formulário, o php vai ser executado novamente, ou seja, todas as variáveis são criadas novamente. Você deve armazenar os valores anteriores em algum lugar, por exemplo, crie uma variável na sessão e cada vez que o valor for enviado, atualize a variável. Você tem que criar a sessão antes de armazenar qualquer valor nela. Veja a [documentação do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php) sobre sessões.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você coloca um número e clica em "Add Array", aquele número vai ser "empurrado" no array `$cesta`. Porem, depois disso você redireciona pro index.php, quando você redireciona, você perde o que estava dentro de `$cesta`, se você quiser persistir tudo o que você manda pra dentro de `$cesta` você tem que usar um banco de dados ou até mesmo sessões.

Levando isso em consideração, segue um exemplo de como você poderia fazer isso:

**HTML**
(aqui não vai mudar nada)

```
<?php
include_once 'update.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Array</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Add</h2>
    <hr>
    <div style="width: 50%; margin-left: 30px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 300px;">
            <form method="POST" action="function/add.php?action=addArray">
                <label for="valor">Valor:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-info">Add Array</button>
            </form>   
    <br>
    <br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!empty($_GET['action']))
{
    switch ($_GET['action']) 
    {
        case 'addArray':
        $cesta = array(); //Cria variavel tipo array.
        $valorInserir = $_POST['valor']; //Atribui valor pra variavel
        array_push($cesta, $valorInserir); //Insere no array CESTA o valor
        $_SESSION['valor'][] = $cesta;
        header("Location: ../index.php"); //Direciona pra index novamente
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; echo print_r($_SESSION['valor']) ; echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Toda vez que você realiza uma nova requisição ao servidor ele interpreta o PHP fazendo com que a variável volte para o valor padrão no caso `$cesta = array()`

Você poderia guardar esse valor em cookies ou sessão.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.session.php