# C# MVC5 EF - Como não perder dados após validação do ModelState?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

segue abaixo minha dúvida caso possam ajudar. Utilizo C# ASP.NET MVC 5 com Entity Framework.

Tenho classes que representam abaixo respectivamente um cadastro de clientes e um cadastro de e-mails:

```
public partial class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Email> { get; set; }
}


public partial class Email
{
    [Key]
    public int EmailId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente  { get; set; }
}
```

Quando crio a view da página de edit do e-mail, gostaria de trazer o nome do cliente (dono do e-mail), mas não para que o usuário possa editá-lo e sim apenas para que ele tenha certeza sobre qual é e-mail que ele está alterando.

Sendo assim, na view faço algo como:

```
@model Models.Cadastro.Email


//[...]


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cliente.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10 txt_disable">
        @Html.ValueFor(model => model.Cliente.Nome)
    </div>
</div>


//[...]
```

Até aí tudo funciona perfeito, o problema é que, quando clico em Salvar, se o ModelState.IsValid for false, essa página voltará com o Nome do cliente em branco, já que a página é preenchida com os dados do último formulário enviado e esse campo (Nome do cliente) não faz parte do Model Email e sim do Model Cliente.

Qual forma vocês sugerem para eu resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, você precisa ter em mente que uma aplicação web é sempre [*stateless* (ou sem estado)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119549/18246). Ou seja, basicamente, o servidor recebe uma requisição, a processa e devolve para o cliente. Não existe um "fluxo contínuo", por assim dizer.

Levando isto em consideração, você já deve ter imaginado o que precisa fazer, certo? Preencher os dados que pretende mostrar na *view* antes de montá-la.

Vou te mostrar duas formas de se fazer isso:

#### 1. Enviar a propriedade de navegação junto com o model

Provavelmente esta é a forma mais indicada porque não vai ser necessário mudar muita coisa no seu código atual.

A *action* que processa o POST deve ser algo assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Email email)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Faça algo para recuperar o "cliente" desta entidade
        email.Cliente = EncontrarCliente(email);
        return View(email);
    }
}
```

Isso vai fazer com que a propriedade de navegação (`Cliente`) esteja preenchida na hora de montar a *view*.

#### 2. Salvar este dado na `ViewBag`

Na *view* ficaria algo assim:

```
@model Models.Cadastro.Email

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Nome do cliente</label>
    <div class="col-md-10 txt_disable">
        @ViewBag.NomeCliente
    </div>
</div>
```

No *controller*, você precisa se certificar de preencher isto sempre que for devolver esta *view*:

Na *action* que processa o GET:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = db.Emails.Include(e => e.Cliente).Find(id);
    /* (^) Aqui fica o código para procurar a entidade no banco */

    ViewBag.NomeCliente = model.Cliente.Nome;

    return View(model);
}
```

E também na *action* que processa o POST:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Email email)
{
    var cliente = EncontrarCliente(email);
    ViewBag.NomeCliente = cliente.Nome;

    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(email);
    }

    // Continua...
}
```

Comment: Legal, LINQ! Eu pensei em fazer com ViewBag mesmo, mas não estava gostando muito da ideia, pois em outras páginas eu vou ter vários desses campos para preencher e teria que mudar muito minha View. Agora essa primeira opção funcionou bem! Obrigado!