# Como receber um valor do javascript dentro de um bloco c# ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

O que eu gostaria de fazer é converter um valor de dentro de um JSON para `Double` e aplicar o `String.Format("{0:N}", valor_JSON));` assim eu estaria convertendo `1000 -> 1.000`.

Porém como já foi respondido não tem a possibilidade de fazer isso dentro da View, pois C# roda no server-side. A solução seria processar isso tudo antes de retornar o JSON, ou utilizar uma biblioteca Javascript para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é possível da forma que você mostra. C# roda no **servidor**, e JavaScript roda **no cliente** (*browser*).

O código C# serve para gerar o HTML (ou CSS ou JS) que vai ser enviado para o navegador. Portanto, uma vez que o código C# foi executado e fez o seu trabalho de gerar um HTML para que o cliente possa recebê-lo, ele não será mais executado até que uma nova requisição seja feita para o servidor.

Eu não consegui entender o propósito do código, então não tenho como te indicar o que fazer. Talvez se você der um contexto e explicar o que quer fazer, posso te dar uma solução em código.

Talvez seja interessante você ler: [O que é um "protocolo sem estado", como o HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119549/18246)

Comment: LINQ, eu quero pegar uma variável do meu JSON retornado, converter em Double para aplicar o `String.Format("{0:N}", ValorRecebidoDoJSONAqui));` assim eu posso converter tipo 1000 em 1.000. Mas pelo visto terei que fazer isso antes de retornar o JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde sei você só consegue fazer isso executando um submit para um método dentro do C#. Para isso você pode criar uma variável form e chamar o método submit, passando os valores que quer por parâmetro.
Exemplo:

```
var myForm = document.createElement("form");
myForm.action = 'url do seu método no C#';
myForm.method = "post";

//Setando o parâmetro
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.value = obj[key];
input.name = key;
myForm.appendChild(input);

//Adiciona o form ao corpo do documento
document.body.appendChild(myForm);
//Envia o formulário
myForm.submit();
```

Lembrando que você pode usar frameworks javascripts do mercado para fazer isso também, como jQuery, AngularJS e outros.