# Como as sessões funcionam em nível HTTP?

Tags: php, session, http

Me deparei com essa questão recentemente e não encontrei muito sobre ela na *web*.

Estou acostumado a trabalhar (e ler) sobre *session* em **PHP**, mas nunca parei para pensar como elas seriam a nível **HTTP**, alguém saberia algo sobre?

Como a sessão é tratada e se comporta a nível **HTTP**?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/91) e [O que é um “protocolo sem estado”, como o HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119549/91)

Comment: [Sessões em PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php) e [Uso básico de Sessões](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.examples.basic.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como é explicado nas respostas citadas [¹](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174116/como-o-protocolo-http-processa-as-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es#answer-174131)  [²](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119549/o-que-%C3%A9-um-protocolo-sem-estado-como-o-http#answer-119554), o HTTP é *stateless*:

> é um protocolo de comunicação que considera cada requisição como uma transação independente que não está relacionada a qualquer requisição anterior, de forma que a comunicação consista de pares de requisição e resposta independentes.

Para tornar possível o armazenamento de estados na conexão, é utilizado um [cookie](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) em um campo específico no `Header HTTP` chamado `HTTP_COOKIE`.