# Laravel 5.6 - variavel global e dinamica

Tags: php, laravel, variáveis

Tenho uma API com laravel 5.6 e necessito criar variaveis globais que ao longo da aplicação podem ter seu valor alterado, porém estou tendo problemas.

Exemplo:
    1. Na primeira requisição seto o valor desta variavel como "teste";
    2. Na segunda requisição quero pegar o valor atual, que deveria ser "teste";

1. Tentei inicialmente usar o config, porém não funcionou;
2. Tentei usar Session, mas tive o mesmo problema;
3. Tentei setar uma variavel na "super controller", onde todas as controller extendem a ela, não funcionou.

O valor da varíavel somente é valido durante a execução da requisição, ou seja, eu faço uma requisção à controller aaaControler, esta faz uso de outras controllers, dentro da mesma requisição o valor persiste, mas finaliza no returno.

Pensei em persistir no banco de dados, criar uma referência e sempre buscar este valor lá, mas será este a melhor forma ?

Peço ajuda nesta questão.

Obrigado.

Comment: jà tentou usando composer?

Comment: Sim, você deve persistir o valor, mas não necessariamente no banco. Em sessão já deveria funcionar, visto que ela serve justamente para isso. Existem ainda outras opções, como persistir em arquivo, memcached, redis, etc. Para entender mais o que está acontecendo, você deve ler sobre como o protocolo HTTP é *stateless*. Comece por [O que é um “protocolo sem estado”, como o HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119549/5878)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer utilizando [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers). O view composer é executado quando a view é carregada, desta forma, você pode passar em um `Closure` com funcionalidades adicionais para determinada view.

Para determinar um composer para todas as views use o coringa `*`;

```php
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('variavel','Valor qualquer');
});
```

> Você pode fazer isto também sem utilizar Closures.

```
View::composer('*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer');
```

View composers são executados quando uma view é renderizada. Porém o laravél possui também `view creators`, que são executados quando uma view é instanciada.

Você pode escolher utilizar também um `BaseController` com um método"setupLayout". Sendo assim, todas as views que forem carregadas, seráo carregadas pelo `setupLayout`, ao qual vai adicionar os dados adicionais que você precisa.

No entanto, Utilizando os views composers, você terá certeza que esta parte do código será executada. Mas utilizando o `BaseController`, a flexibilidade é maior pois você pode evitar de carregar os dados extras.

Você pode utilizar ainda o view share.